# get location VB.net

Tags: vb.net, location, show

I am trying to load google maps into a vb.net webbrowser control and "Show My Location".

I can load google maps into the web browser control but cannot work out to emulate clicking the "Show My Location" button that is in google maps when loaded from a browser such as fireofx or IE.

EG"

```
Private Sub googleMAPS_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://maps.google.com.au/maps?hl=en&Show My Location")
End Sub
```

thx

Comment: What do you ultimately want to achieve because I guarantee there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Google has an entire API suite for map related interactions. If you click on the advanced options tab at [this](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html) site, it provides more options (if you are interested in more than just a static location - Not sure, so I posted the simpler link).